# Connecting multiple Contacts to list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

I have gone through quite a bit of messages and haven't yet found exactly what I am looking for.  I am wanting to connect contacts to a list item.  For instance, I am creating a list of servers within an organization and each of those servers will have multiple contacts.  A server might have a line of business contact, support contact, vendor contact, etc. All contacts could be connected to multiple servers.  My intention is to have a tabbed view which will have a tab with general server information, a tab with applications on the server and a tab that lists all contacts for a server and their roles.

I might be over-complicating this, but does anyone have a suggestion on how to proceed?  Can this be done out of the box?

Thanks for any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as arranging the data in lists there are two fairly straight forward methods:

1. Use a single list and create people columns.  Your contacts are directly associated with the server item.
2. Use a lookup column type to associate the server list with contacts list.  You need to provide criteria for matching to make it work. You can use multiple look ups if needed.

Be aware of the list throttling - you can't create a view with more than 8 lookup columns. People columns are considered lookups.

As for displaying the data in a "tabbed" view you need to create that your self.

You can:

1. Create custom XSLT for data view web part
2. Use the content query web part with custom XSLT
3. Content Search web part in 2013 with custom display template
4. You may be able to get away with some JQuery magic on page with a default list

Depending on how you go about this you may not even need the above "relationships" you can say use something like JQuery and SPServices to query the lists and create the relationships as well as build your interface around it.